# Architeture of voting based website/app

Tags: caching, architecture, redis

I am working on a website. I wanted to get feedback on the design. Website function similar to Reddit, ProductHunt etc (i.e. voting based). Here is the overview 
1. Backend service gets posts from the web and store into DB. 
2. Posts are displayed on the website (top, new). 
3. Top section shows website based on ranking (votes, time factors). 
4. On scroll, user see more posts

Design:

Database tables: Posts, Users, Votes

Backend service:
backend service fetches posts from the web periodically and stores into DB ( Posts table).

Website: 
When user visits website user sees Top posts. On request, website code queries database which returns links ranked based on time and votes. When use votes particular post, website code adds it to database. Website allows login and stores user info in User table.

Question: 
**Should I consider using Redis cache instead of querying database to get ranked posts on every request? If yes then what should be stored in to cache and what should be the logic of updating cache?**

If I end up using cache then cache should have two entries. 1. Ranked posts 1. New posts. For ranked post should backend service update cache periodically? and for New posts should I invalidate cache whenever new post fetched from web?

Also how to deal with infinite scroll if I go with cache route? Example: User see posts based on ranking. User scrolls for new posts after 15 minutes. by that time ranking could have changed.

I would appreciate any feedback/help!

Answer (score 0):

I think Redis will help you here a lot in terms of performance and you can use it as a cache and also as a real database (it has everything you need - persistence, backup, master-slave replication, server side cluster). 
If you want to use it as a cache, this is what you can do:

- For the ranked posts you can use the [Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-sorted-sets). This will allow you to have a score per post which will be the number of votes and it will keep your posts sorted based on this score. You have a command for increasing the score of an existing post - [ZINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby). You can update the cache in the same time when you update the database
- For the new posts you can use [lists](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-lists), because you can easily add elements in front of the list, when a new post is created, using [LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) and also keep it of a fixed length using [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim)
- For the infinite scrolling there are more solutions, all with their price: you can use the command [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) with Limit parameter to get the items 
  ordered, so if something changes in the meantime you might not display it
- Also whenever you would need to do 2 or more commands in an atomic way, for example if you want for the new posts created to keep always the latest 50 you need to call LPUSH and LTRIM as one command, you can do this with [LUA Scripting](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

Comment: Thank you @Liviu  ! This is very helpful indeed. I still am not able to figure out paging. Lets take an example: ordered set based on votes: a, b, x, g, d, e, c, f, y, s. 10 items orders based on votes. page displays 5 items. when user scrolls next 5 items gets displayed. before user scrolls for next items, set changes and hence order of post. New set looks like: a, b, f, y, x, g, s, d, e, c. Some of items from top 5 moved to next bucket and some of items from second page moved to first. scrolling will give duplicate items as well as it will miss some items.

Comment: No perfect solution for this, easiest way create a snapshot when the user asks for it (which can consume a lot of memory if you have many concurrent users). But if you want to have a cursor on server you need some id to forward on it and not on size of the set. In your case if the score can go only UP then it is possible to use it. The last element you received on first page was d, so you need to remember its score and when asking for second page you ask only from that score down, so you should only receive e and c and thus avoiding duplicates. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines